What exactly is the significance of $a_{\phi}$ component in cylindrical co-ordinate system?
{ N.B: I have already looked for the answer in the following question but didn't quite get what I am looking for:
What does phi component of a cylindrical coordinate signifies? }
Let us say we have a point $P(5,120^\circ ,2)$ : if we had to express it in vectors then the corresponding position vector would be, $$\overrightarrow{OP} = 5\underline{a_p} + 0\underline{a_\phi} + 2\underline{a_z} $$
It is evident that whatever point we take the $\phi$ component of the position vector always turns out to be zero. I don't exactly know the answer but so far what I could understand is that if we imagine the pictorial representation then it is quite easier to understand that the two other components are enough to express the position. But then what is the necessity of the $\phi$ component?
Again let us suppose we only know $\overrightarrow{OP}$ not exactly the coordinate, then how are we supposed to determine the coordinates of $P$ from that vector?

What happens in cylindrial coordinates is that the 'unit' vectors are no longer constant. $\phi$ determines $a_p$, that's how it is needed.

I did understand upto that much but how can we determine $\phi$ from $a_\rho$

Is that any help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Conventions

@Ingix well I understood the azimuth in coordinate system but didn't quite understand its component in vector

How can we exactly extract the information of $\phi$ from a given vector in cylindrical coordinate system? e.g: for $\overrightarrow{A} = A_\rho a_\rho + A_\phi a_\phi + A_z a_z$ what is the value of $\phi$?

I think there is a misconception that coordinate systems work by having a unit vector for each component and the vector to a point is the linear combination of the components with those units vectors. Some work that way, and the standard cartesian coordinate system is one where additionally the unit vectors are fixed.
But for the cylindrical coordinate system that is not what happens. You have a fixed vertical unit vector $a_z$, but the polar unit vector $a_p$ varies, and how it varies depends on $\phi$! We have
$$a_p = (\cos \phi, \sin \phi)^T $$
where this vector is to be interpreted in a standard cartesion planar coordinate system, where the $x$-axis is the polar axis $L$ (as taken from initial picture in Wikipedia).
The vector to a point $P$ represented as $(r, \phi, z)^T$ in cylindrical coordinates is then
$$\vec{P}=ra_p + za_z,$$
without a summand belonging to the $\phi$ component. That component had its influence in determining the $a_p$ unit vector.

I have understood your explanation but I had a slight confusion regarding the determination of $\phi$ solely from a vector represented in cylindrical form
